# AFNetworking 2.0 working with valid certificates

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, ios7, afnetworking

I am working with AFNetworking 2.0 using AFHTTPURLSessionManager on ios 7. Our development server had until recently a self signed certificate. They changed it with an official certificate from GoDaddy. On web browser it looks fine, but afnetwoking can't pass the validation challenge any more. Do I need to change the pinning mode to something else? (I've tried certificate and none with no luck). I've disabled the allowInvalidCertificates but it's the same. 
How should this be done properly? What if I want the app to work both with selfsigned certificates and official ones? (I can change the server addres inside the app and some servers might not have the signed certificate)

Comment: Did you add the new certificate file to your bundle?  You should only need to (1) add both certificates to your bundle, and (2) set your SSL Pinning Mode.

Comment: As I understand it, if the certificate is valid and Signed by a Certificate Authority, you shouldn't need to add it to the bundle. That's something the OS should take care about since it has the CA's root certificate.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were using SSL Pinning, in which you whitelist some certs and reject everything else.

Comment: Do you have certs in your app's bundle?  What specific version of AFNetworking are you using?  (2.0.1? 2.1?)  How is your `AFSecurityPolicy` configured?